# Codeigniter omit where clause for empty criterion

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays, codeigniter

I have a page for browsing db records. The viewer can filter records by category, author, and tags. I'm using a form instead of url segments for filtering records (it feels more secure because I can validate inputs.)

For instance, when all form inputs are populated the query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (`posts`) WHERE `category` = 'technolgy' AND `author` = 'lila' AND `tags` = 'ebook'
```

However if one input or more is empty, I get no results. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM (`posts`) WHERE `category` = '' AND `author` = 'lila' AND `tags` = ''
```

I want the inputs to be optional so for example if just `author name` is entered, I can return records made by that author regardless of category and tags. How can I omit the `and where` clause if empty?

Note: `or_where` clause is not the solution because it doesn't return a precise query if all filter inputs all filled.

My Model

```
function filter($form_values)
    {                       
        $query = $this->db->get('posts');           
        $this->db->where($form_values); //adds clause to all array items
        return $query->result();        
    }
```

The function parameter is an array with input values from my view. Example,

```
$form_values = array('category' => $category, 'author' => $author, 'tags' => $tags);
```

and my View

```
$form_values = array (                  
                'category' => $this->input->post('category'),
                'author'   => $this->input->post('author'),
                'tags'     => $this->input->post('tags')
            );

$this->Records_model->filter($form_values);
```

I know that in Codeigniter if `$_POST'` are empty they are set to `FALSE`. Can that be used to achieve what I'm trying? I'm not sure if I'm on the right track

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that `$this->input->post()` will return `FALSE` if the `$_POST` value is not set. Unless you specifically want `IS NULL` to be part of the query (which I *believe* will happen by passing `FALSE` to param 2 of `where()`, not 100% sure), just filter out the empty values:

```
function filter($form_values)
{              
    $form_values = array_filter($form_values);

    // NOTE:
    // where() needs to be called first, or your query won't use the WHERE clause

    // You may need to make sure there is at least one value in $form_values
    if ( ! empty($form_values)) // however you wish to check for a value
    {
        $this->db->where($form_values); //adds clause to all array items
    }

    $query = $this->db->get('posts');           

    return $query->result();        
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

The important part to note on `array_filter()`:

> If no callback is supplied, all entries of input equal to FALSE (see converting to boolean) will be removed.

Comment: I don't want to put this in the answer, but you could optionally throw `$_POST` at the `filter()` method instead of building the array in the controller.

Comment: Wow you're brilliant! I don't think there is a better solution for this :) Calling `where()` before the `get()` didn't seem to work but `get()` above the if statement works.

Comment: I am very doubtful about that statement, are you sure? As soon as you call `get()`, the query you build is destroyed unless you are caching it. You need to call `where()` first.

Comment: Yes, I'm absolutely sure, I have tested. http://codepaste.dev7studios.com/item/x6i18nq9n

Comment: OK, well as long as you're getting the results you want. Check out [the source](https://bitbucket.org/ellislab/codeigniter/src/f83ccd9a1f59/system/database/DB_active_rec.php#cl-966) though, particularly the call to [`_reset_select()`](https://bitbucket.org/ellislab/codeigniter/src/f83ccd9a1f59/system/database/DB_active_rec.php#cl-2017). Just make sure you test, I can't determine anything from a pastie.

Comment: Ok I think I sorted it out. In my controller I was calling the model function and also the model index function which has no `WHERE` clause. I removed the second function and now it works only when `where()` is called first